# Set some value with "Confirm credential PIN" screen and get "After accept challenge"

Tags: android, authentication, encryption, android-6.0-marshmallow, fingerprint

I am new in Android application development and I want to use Google confirm credential demo app in our application.

In my application I have created a symmetric key. I want to get this key after successfully confirming PIN or password. However when I try to encrypt then it always returns a new key while I want to get same key. In that way I can use this key every successful authentication.

I want to combine PIN, pattern or fingerprint with a particular user (some string) and get this user after the user is successfully authenticated.

Please suggest me how to merge user name or some string with confirm credential dialog. Or suggest a different way.

Here is what I am doing:

1. I have generated key;
2. then show confirmation screen;
3. get result in `onActivityresult`;
4. then call try encrypt.

When i call try encrypt then its return me different key always. Here I want same data when I was set at the time of generate key. Here is my source code where I am  generating and getting Key.

```
public boolean createKey() {
    if(mEncreaptedKey!=null)return false;
    // Generate a key to decrypt payment credentials, tokens, etc.
    // This will most likely be a registration step for the user when they are setting up your app.
    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            mKeyStore = null;
            mKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
            mKeyStore.load(null);
        KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(
                KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore");

        // Set the alias of the entry in Android KeyStore where the key will appear
        // and the constrains (purposes) in the constructor of the Builder

            KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder builder=new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(ACCESS_TOKEN,
                    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                    .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                    .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                    .setAlgorithmParameterSpec(new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1"))
                    .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
                    // Require that the user has unlocked in the last 30 seconds
                    .setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(AUTHENTICATION_DURATION_SECONDS)
                    .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                builder.setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment(false);
            }
            builder.build();
            keyGenerator.init(builder.build());
             key=  keyGenerator.generateKey();
        }else{

        }

        return true;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException
            | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | KeyStoreException
            | CertificateException | IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create a symmetric key", e);
    }
}


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public boolean tryEncrypt(Context context) {
    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            mKeyStore.load(null);
        SecretKey secretKey = (SecretKey) mKeyStore.getKey(ACCESS_TOKEN, null);
            mCipher= Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);

        // Try encrypting something, it will only work if the user authenticated within
        // the last AUTHENTICATION_DURATION_SECONDS seconds.
            mCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            byte[] encryptionIv = mCipher.getIV();
        byte[] results = mCipher.doFinal(ACCESS_TOKEN.getBytes(CHARSET_NAME));
        String cipher1 = Base64.encodeToString(results, Base64.DEFAULT);
        mEncreaptedKey = Base64.encodeToString(cipher1.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);

        // If the user has recently authenticated, you will reach here.
        // showAlreadyAuthenticated();
        return true;
    }
    } catch (UserNotAuthenticatedException e) {
        // User is not authenticated, let's authenticate with device credentials.
       // showAuthenticationScreen();
        return false;
    } catch (KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException e) {
        // This happens if the lock screen has been disabled or reset after the key was
        // generated after the key was generated.
        Toast.makeText(context, "Keys are invalidated after created. Retry the purchase\n"
                        + e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    } catch (BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException | KeyStoreException |
             UnrecoverableKeyException
            | NoSuchPaddingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I understand that English is not your first language, but you can always use uppercase for "I" and for names. Misspelling "key" is also not something I would expect if you'd reread or spell checked your question. Please do try and format your question to the best of your abilities. As for your problem: please show us your code for generating the key or your question is likely to be closed. Note that code requests are certainly deemed off topic.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thanks, for your support about asking question. I have edited my question with source code. Please help me for this problem. Thanks in advance.